# User Profile Inactive Profiles Not Deleting

Tags: user-profile, my-site, profile-sync

In the SharePoint farm we have, the inactive user profiles (those are disabled in AD) are not being removed when i am running the my site cleanup timer job. I verified the configuration of User Profile and found the following steps

1. I have configured my site host for the User Profile
2. When I run the profile synchronization I observe that in
   MISCLINET (Forefront Client) it’s marking the profiles for deleting
   (i.e., it showing deletes value to 138 which are the total inactive
   profiles I have)
3. But when I query the Profile Database(UserProfile_Full table)
   it’s showing the bDeleted = 1 instead of 0 for all the profiles.
4. And I observed that the inactive profiles are not being moved to
   the "Missing from Import Sub type".
5. Then, when I run the my site clean up timer job it’s finishing the
   job in 0 seconds which means that the job is not running
   successfully.

I am following this MSDN article for solving it 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2012/06/25/top-recommendations-for-managing-the-my-site-cleanup-timer-job.aspx

Comment: Are you running a 'Full' sync?

Answer (score 1):

You can use below workaround.

The “SharePoint Active Directory Import” does not mark the profile to be deleted either with incremental or Full Import when they are the disabled and only way to remove the obsolete users is as mentioned HERE https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff681014(v=office.15).aspx#RemoveObsUsers.

1 Run Full Import

2 Post that run Use SharePoint Management Shell to Run following

```
a) $upa = Get-SPServiceApplication -id <Identity of User Profile Service Application>

b) Set-SPProfileServiceApplication -Identity $upa - PurgeNonImportedObjects $true
```

Comment: This helped me...